How to apply two colors to a 3D plot based on x domain in PGFPlots?
I am trying to plot several normal distributions in 3D using pgfplots. I want to color each normal distribution with two different colors depending on the value of ( x ). Specifically, I want the plot to use one color for ( x \leq 100 ) and another color for ( x > 100 ).

Here is my current approach:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
    myaxis/.style={
        xlabel = $\text{Spot}$,
        ylabel = Time to maturity,
        zlabel = Prime,
        samples=100,
        domain=95:105,
        samples y=0,
        ytick=data,
        zmin=0,
        view={0}{60},
    },
    myarea/.style={
        fill opacity=0.20,
        draw=none,
        fill=blue!50,
        mark=none,
        smooth,
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[myaxis]
        
            % Problem here => \addplot3 [myarea,restrict x to domain=95:100,red] (x,4,{normal(100,1.5)});           
            
            % Problem here too=> \addplot3 [myarea,domain=95:100,red] (x,4,{normal(100,1.5)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,4,{normal(100,1.5)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,3,{normal(100,1.25)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,2,{normal(100,1.00)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,1,{normal(100,0.75)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,0,{normal(100,0.5)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}

However, this code produces unexpected results. The plots do not display as I intended with the specified colors for the different domains of x.

What am I missing or doing wrong? How can I correctly apply two different colors to each normal distribution based on the value of x using restrict x to domain?

The pgfplot documentation says:

Use \closedcycle whenever you intend to fill the area under a plot.

I have colored only one curve to keep the answer minimal.
Edit: Instead of restrict x to domain=95:100, I have used only domain=95:100. The former leaves a little gap between the intervals. Thanks @hpekristiansen
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{
    myaxis/.style={
        xlabel = $\text{Spot}$,
        ylabel = Time to maturity,
        zlabel = Prime,
        samples=200,
        domain=95:105,
        samples y=0,
        ytick=data,
        zmin=0,
        view={0}{60},
    },
    myarea/.style={
        fill opacity=0.20,
        draw=none,
        fill=blue!50,
        mark=none,
        smooth,
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[myaxis]
        
            \addplot3 [myarea, domain=95:100,red] (x,4,{normal(100,1.5)}) \closedcycle;
            \addplot3 [myarea, domain=100:105,yellow] (x,4,{normal(100,1.5)}) \closedcycle;  
            
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,3,{normal(100,1.25)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,2,{normal(100,1.00)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,1,{normal(100,0.75)});
            \addplot3 [myarea] (x,0,{normal(100,0.5)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}



Do not use restrict x to domain - that is not what you want. Use domain.
